# Is it possible to force div to take height of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

We are using bootstrap library for styling. We have a div and we want the div to take the height of the screen. I do not want to set min or max height.

I can set the height through javascript but I am just curious if I can force the div to take height of the screen through CSS. Do we have any option apart from using media query?

Comment: When you say the "*height of the screen*" do you mean the height of the user's monitor screen (whether or not the user has their browser full-screen) or the full height of the view-port of the browser?

Comment: if you are not targeting old browsers, checkout vh http://codepen.io/devtips/pen/XJByvr/

Comment: @DavidThomas: I meant viewport. Thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use vh. vh is viewport height. You can find more about it [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Isn't it viewport-height?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you want.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Hello World </h1>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/mymj1gfb/1/)

Comment: Hi, for better understanding, I have given a bg color too. http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/mymj1gfb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do by using `position`. Say you have the `div` as `.mask`:

```css
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```